# NextJs server component rerenders when setting state in client component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

In a NextJs application, I have a server component which queries data and then passes the data into a client component to display it. In the client component I use the `useState` hook to hide/show some stuff. The problem is that every time I use the `useState` hook, the server component rerenders and requeries the data and displays the rendering skeleton while doing so. I am expecting the client component to simply hide/show elements locally. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show your code, so we could try to reproduce it locally?